# add to the end of line character in a loop ruby

Tags: ruby

Have a string, and a range of numbers.Start = 2

It is necessary to get an array of

```
arraystring=[line2, line3 ... line20]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please improve your code formatting (and probably variable naming). Remember: 28 people "had" to read this already. Also please formulate a question (with a "?" at the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
arraystring = []
for i in 2..20
   arraystring << 'line' + i.to_s
end
```

Comment: You could use `map` to make this a one-liner: `arr = (2..20).map { |num| 'line' + num.to_s}`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly the following should do the trick:

```
first = 2
last = 20
array_string = Array.new(last - first + 1) { |i| "line#{i + first}" }
```

The constructor for `Array` can take a size argument, and a block which can be used to define the elements.  Thus the creation of the array is a one-liner.  I've separated out the range specification to highlight the generality.